# Are all algorithms with a constant base to the n (e.g.: k^n) of the same time complexity?

Tags: performance, algorithm, math, big-o, time-complexity

In this example: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E%281000000000%2F2%29+%3C+%283%2F2%29%5E1000000000

I noticed that those two equations are pretty similar no matter how high you go in `n`. Do all algorithms with a constant to the `n` fall in the same time complexity category? Such as 2^n, 3^n, 4^n, etc.

Comment: That example doesn't really show anything about algorithmic complexity. No, 2^n is not the same complexity as 3^n. Do you want a proof?

Comment: They are in the same category, This does not mean their complexity is the same. They are exponential running time algorithms. Obviously 2^n < 4^n

Comment: @elbek: You're right, I spoke carelessly; they are in the same category, but not equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are in the same category, This does not mean their complexity is the same. They are exponential running time algorithms. Obviously 2^n < 4^n

We can see `4^n/2^n = 2^2n/2^n = 2^n` 
This means `4^n` algorithm exponential slower(`2^n` times) than `2^n`
The same thing happens with `3^n` which is `1.5^n`.
But this does not mean 2^n is something far less than 4^n, It is still exponential and will not be feasible when n>50.

Note this is happening due to n is not in the base. If they were in the base like this:
4n^k vs n^k then this 2 algorithms are asymptotically the same(as long as n is relatively small than actually data size). They would be different by linear time, just like `O(n) vs c * O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

The time complexities O(a<sup>n</sup>) and O(b<sup>n</sup>) are *not* the same if 1 < a < b.  As a quick proof, we can use the formal definition of big-O notation to show that b<sup>n</sup> ≠ O(a<sup>n</sup>).

This works by contradiction.  Suppose that b<sup>n</sup> = O(a<sup>n</sup>) and that 1 < a < b.  Then there must be some c and n<sub>0</sub> such that for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>, we have that b<sup>n</sup> ≤ c · a<sup>n</sup>.  This means that b<sup>n</sup> / a<sup>n</sup> ≤ c for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>.  Since b > a, it should start to become clear that this is impossible - as n grows larger, b<sup>n</sup> / a<sup>n</sup> = (b / a)<sup>n</sup> will get larger and larger.  In particular, if we pick any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub> such that n > log<sub>b / a</sub> c, then we will have that

> (b / a)<sup>n</sup> > (b / a)<sup>log(b/a) c</sup> = c

So, if we pick n = max{n<sub>0</sub>, c + 1}, then it's not true that b<sup>n</sup> ≤ c · a<sup>n</sup>, contradicting our assumption that b<sup>n</sup> = O(a<sup>n</sup>).

This means, in particular, that O(2<sup>n</sup>) ≠ O(1.5<sup>n</sup>) and that O(3<sup>n</sup>) ≠ O(2<sup>n</sup>).  This is why when using big-O notation, it's still necessary to specify the base of any exponents that end up getting used.

One more thing to notice - although it looks like 2<sup>1000000000/2</sup> is approximately 1.4<sup>1000000000/2</sup>, notice that these are totally different numbers.  The first is of the form 10<sup>10<sup>8.1</sup></sup>ish and the second of the form 10<sup>10</sup>8.2ish.  That might not seem like a big difference, but it's absolutely colossal.  Take, for example, 10<sup>10<sup>1</sup></sup> and 10<sup>10<sup>2</sup></sup>.  This first number is 10<sup>10</sup>, which is 10 billion and takes ten digits to write out.  The second is 10<sup>100</sup>, one googol, which takes 100 digits to write out.  There's a huge difference between them - the first of them is close to the world population, while the second is about the total number of atoms in the universe!

Hope this helps!